# How to stream a video from Database to be shown with Html5 in Asp.Net MVC3?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, video-streaming

I'm developing for showing videos and I need to save the video on Sql Server and displaying them with Html5 in my views, is it possible to do so? doea it make any diffrence with downloading files? does it cause much overhead on my server? thanks

Comment: Unless it's a very short video, storing it in the database is a pretty bad idea.  Not only does it needlessly bloat your database, but there is usually very little benefit from it.  You should instead prefer to store large media on the local filesystem, or a shared filesystem (if in a web farm situation).  Do you have any specific reason why you want to store it in the database?

Comment: The last version of sql server doesn't have any problems with large blobs as it just creates a pointer to filesystem directly and doesnt page the data.

@ePezhman you have to define what you mean by streaming. Do you intend to use websockets? Http long polling? Swf files your users will download and play?

Comment: @MihalisBagos - Your comment is misleading.  Yes, SQL 2008 offers the FileStreaming storage feature, but this doesn't happen automatically, and there is no support for it in Entity Framework.  You have to specifically write code to use it, and your database must be configured to use it.  If you just use standard blobs, the problem with large blobs is still there.

Comment: @MystereMan - This problem is exactly the problem FileTables http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx were created to address in SQL 2012 which is actually the latest version. There is no mention of Entity Framework, and since this a specific implementation... Well... You implement specific code. However storage is not the only problem here

Comment: @MihalisBagos - My problem is that you made it sound like blobs in general are not a problem anymore, and that all blobs use this feature.  That's misleading.  Just because FileStream storage was created for this reason doesn't make normal blobs suddenly not a problem anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're determined to use SQL to store this, then you might want to consider the SQL Server FileStream storage option (Only available in SQL 2008+).  There is very little support for this in Entity Framework though, so you would probably want to use something like SqlFileStream object in .NET (assuming you're using .net)

Here's a decent article on the subject.  But again, I would strongly recommend not store it in the database.

http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/using-sqlfilestream-in-c-to-access-sql-server-filestream-data/